# The proof that Finding all simple paths between two nodes in an undirected graph is NP

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete, np-hard

The topology is given and undirected. Given 2 nodes s,t. Then find all simple paths (no cycle) between s and t. As far as I know, it's a NPC or NP-hard problem. But I read plenty of references and found no proof in details. Could someone help me and give a paper or web link about it?

Comment: Another problem. In a given topology, 2 nodes s,t. Then find a simple path set that these simple paths (starting and ending points are s and t, respectively), traverse each node at least k times. Is it still NPC or NP-hard?

Comment: I don't believe this problem is NP-hard due to the fact that "list all solutions" problems typically aren't in NP. Check [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/63422/complexity-classes-pertaining-to-listing-all-solutions) for more details.

Comment: I've found a paper proved the number of all simple pahts is #P-complete

Comment: I'd believe that *counting* the number of simple paths, but actually *listing* them doesn't seem to fall nicely into any "common" complexity class.